# Removing whitespace when using splat operator

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following code:

```
print(*[((i+1) * '*' + '\n') for i in range(rows)])
```

which produces the output:

```
*
 **
 ***
 ****
 *****
```

The desired output is:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Sticking with a single line, how can this be done? I tried using `.strip(' ')` like so:

```
print(*[((i+1) * '*' + '\n').strip(' ') for i in range(rows)])
```

But it produces the same result. Same with `.replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `sep` parameter as an empty string:

```
>>> print(*[((i+1) * '*' + '\n') for i in range(rows)], sep='')
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Or use `'\n'.join` to build the string before printing:

```
>>> print('\n'.join((i+1) * '*' for i in range(rows)))
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Quicker than me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired output in two ways. If you insist on using argument expansion (the "splat operator"), you can pass `sep=''`. Alternatively you can just construct the string you want with `join`:

```
print('\n'.join((i+1) * '*' for i in range(rows)))
```